# Python to Apk using Google Colab

Tags: python, json, kivy, apk, kivymd

While converting my app developed using python to apk using Google Colab. I get an error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for json

What can be done about this.
My app works seamlessly in my PC.

Requirements in Buildozer
requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.1,json==2.0.9,requests==2.27.1,pillow

I have tried mentioning the specific version of json but that didn't work out.
Please help me out.

Comment: Is your version of `json` in your PC exactly `json==2.0.9`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try without giving a specific version to json, so don't give json a version instead just leave it to "json" and see if that works.